# What is the correct format for ContextRecordID for a constituent record from Blackbaud CRM? (Error converting data type)

Tags: python-3.x, xml, soap, blackbaud

I'm trying to make an API call to a Blackbaud CRM for a data list containing a constituent's email addresses. I've formatted the SOAP request as a jinja2 template, and I'm using python and requests to make the call. This is the spec for the SOAP request:

```
POST /1234ABC_fa123b46-12a4-4119-a334-5678e2e59d29/appfxwebservice.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: bbisec04pro.blackbaudhosting.com
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "Blackbaud.AppFx.WebService.API.1/DataListLoad"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <DataListLoadRequest xmlns="Blackbaud.AppFx.WebService.API.1">
      <DataListID>guid</DataListID>
      <DataListName>string</DataListName>
      <ContextRecordID>string</ContextRecordID>
      <Parameters>
        <Values xmlns="bb_appfx_dataforms">
          <fv ID="string">
            <Value />
            <ValueTranslation>string</ValueTranslation>
          </fv>
          <fv ID="string">
            <Value />
            <ValueTranslation>string</ValueTranslation>
          </fv>
        </Values>
      </Parameters>
      <MaxRows>int</MaxRows>
      <MaxTotalRecords>int</MaxTotalRecords>
      <ViewFormID>guid</ViewFormID>
      <RecordIDColumn>string</RecordIDColumn>
      <IncludeMetaData>boolean</IncludeMetaData>
      <SecurityContext>
        <SecurityFeatureID>guid</SecurityFeatureID>
        <SecurityFeatureType>None or Form or DataList or RecordOperation or BusinessProcess or Dashboard or SearchList or SimpleDataList or Task or SmartQuery or AdHocQueryView or BatchType or AddCodeTableEntry or UpdateCodeTableEntry or DeleteCodeTableEntry or Batch or BatchTemplate or Kpi or MergeTask or SmartField or GlobalChange or ReportParameter or SystemPrivilege or ConfigurationData or BatchTemplateCustomize or BatchProcessor or Page or MapEntity or ExportDefinition</SecurityFeatureType>
        <RecordContext>
          <RecordID>string</RecordID>
          <RecordType>string</RecordType>
        </RecordContext>
        <AttributeContext>
          <AttributeCategoryID>string</AttributeCategoryID>
        </AttributeContext>
      </SecurityContext>
      <IgnoreInvalidFilters>boolean</IgnoreInvalidFilters>
      <ResultsAsXml>boolean</ResultsAsXml>
      <UserSettingsPath>string</UserSettingsPath>
      <SortFieldID>string</SortFieldID>
      <SortDirection>Ascending or Descending</SortDirection>
      <StartRowIndex>int</StartRowIndex>
      <RecordToInclude>string</RecordToInclude>
      <RowRangeKeyToRemove>string</RowRangeKeyToRemove>
      <CancelID>string</CancelID>
      <IgnoreExtraFields>boolean</IgnoreExtraFields>
    </DataListLoadRequest>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Here's my jinja2 template:

```
{% extends 'client_app.xml' %}
{% block request %}<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
               xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <DataListLoadRequest xmlns="Blackbaud.AppFx.WebService.API.1">
      {% block client_app %}{{ super() }}{% endblock %}
      {% if guid %}<DataListID>{{ guid }}</DataListID>{% endif %}
      {% if name %}<DataListName>{{ name }}</DataListName>{% endif %}
      <ContextRecordID>{{ lookup_id }}</ContextRecordID>
      {%  if parameters %}<Parameters>
        <Values xmlns="bb_appfx_dataforms">
          {% for item in parameters %}
          <fv ID="{{ item['id'] }}">
            <Value />
            <ValueTranslation>{{ item['translation'] }}</ValueTranslation>
          </fv>
          {% endfor %}
        </Values>
      </Parameters>{% endif %}
      {% if max_rows %}<MaxRows>{{ max_rows }}</MaxRows>{% endif %}
      {% if max_total %}<MaxTotalRecords>{{ max_total }}</MaxTotalRecords>{% endif %}
      {% if view_id %}<ViewFormID>{{ view_id }}</ViewFormID>{% endif %}
      {% if record_id_col %}<RecordIDColumn>{{ record_id_col }}</RecordIDColumn>{% endif %}
      {% if has_metadata %}<IncludeMetaData>{{ has_metadata }}</IncludeMetaData>{% endif %}
      {% if security_context %}<SecurityContext>
        {% if security_context['guid'] %}<SecurityFeatureID>{{ security_context['guid'] }}</SecurityFeatureID>{% endif %}
        {% if security_context['feature_type'] %}<SecurityFeatureType>{{ security_context['feature_type'] }}</SecurityFeatureType>{% endif %}
        {% if security_context['record'] %}<RecordContext>
          <RecordID>{{ security_context['record']['id'] }}</RecordID>
          <RecordType>{{ security_context['record']['type'] }}</RecordType>
        </RecordContext>{% endif %}
        {% if attribute_context %}<AttributeContext>
          <AttributeCategoryID>{{ attribute_context}}</AttributeCategoryID>
        </AttributeContext>{% endif %}
      </SecurityContext>{% endif %}
      {% if ignore_invalids %}<IgnoreInvalidFilters>{{ ignore_invalids }}</IgnoreInvalidFilters>{% endif %}
      <ResultsAsXml>{{ xml_result }}</ResultsAsXml>
      {% if settings_path %}<UserSettingsPath>{{ settings_path }}</UserSettingsPath>{% endif %}
      {% if sort_id %}<SortFieldID>{{ sort_id }}</SortFieldID>{% endif %}
      {% if sort_direction %}<SortDirection>{{ sort_direction }}</SortDirection>{% endif %}
      {% if start %}<StartRowIndex>{{ start }}</StartRowIndex>{% endif %}
      {% if rec_to_include %}<RecordToInclude>{{ rec_to_include }}</RecordToInclude>{% endif %}
      {% if to_remove %}<RowRangeKeyToRemove>{{ to_remove }}</RowRangeKeyToRemove>{% endif %}
      {% if cancel_id %}<CancelID>{{ cancel_id }}</CancelID>{% endif %}
      {% if ignore_extra %}<IgnoreExtraFields>{{ ignore_extra }}</IgnoreExtraFields>{% endif %}
    </DataListLoadRequest>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
{% endblock %}
```

Here's the code rendering the template:

```
def render_data_list(
        guid='',
        name='',
        lookup_id='',
        parameters='',
        max_rows='',
        max_total='',
        view_id='',
        record_id_col='',
        has_metadata='',
        security_context='',
        ignore_invalids='',
        xml_result=0,
        settings_path='',
        sort_id='',
        sort_direction='',
        start='',
        rec_to_include='',
        to_remove='',
        cancel_id='',
        ignore_extra='',
):
    template = env.get_template('data_list_load.xml')
    return template.render(
        guid=guid,
        name=name,
        lookup_id=lookup_id,
        parameters=parameters,
        max_rows=max_rows,
        max_total=max_total,
        view_id=view_id,
        record_id_col=record_id_col,
        has_metadata=has_metadata,
        security_context=security_context,
        ignore_invalids=ignore_invalids,
        xml_result=xml_result,
        settings_path=settings_path,
        sort_id=sort_id,
        sort_direction=sort_direction,
        start=start,
        rec_to_include=rec_to_include,
        to_remove=to_remove,
        cancel_id=cancel_id,
        ignore_extra=ignore_extra,
    )
```

Here's the function that actually makes the call:

```
def get_list(guid='', name='', lookup_id=''):
    endpoint = 'Blackbaud.AppFx.WebService.API.1/DataListLoad'
    header = config.default_head.copy()
    header.update({'SOAPAction': endpoint})
    body = render_data_list(guid=guid, name=name, lookup_id=lookup_id)
    res = config.session.post(
        f'{config.base_url}{config.db_id}{config.api}',
        data=body,
        headers=header,
    )
    print(res.status_code, res.text)
```

Here's the actual API call with parameters:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(get_list(guid=config.email_list_guid, lookup_id=12345678))
```

I'm getting an error saying "Unable to load data list.  Error converting data type nvarchar to uniqueidentifier." I tried passing a string to `lookup_id` but I still received the same error. I tried to remove the `<ContextRecordID>` tags from the template, but those appear to be required. I'm using a constituent Lookup ID from Blackbaud CRM as the ContextRecordID since the ContextRecordType for this data list is a constituent. Should I be using something else as the ContextRecordID, or is the format of my lookup ID incorrect? Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. Here's the full error response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Header><ResponseErrorHeader xmlns="Blackbaud.AppFx.WebService.API.1"><Name>DataListLoad</Name><ErrorCode>GeneralError</ErrorCode><ErrorText>Unable to load data list.  Error converting data type nvarchar to uniqueidentifier.</ErrorText><ExceptionDetails>Blackbaud.AppFx.Server.ServiceException: Unable to load data list.  Error converting data type nvarchar to uniqueidentifier. ---&gt; System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Error converting data type nvarchar to uniqueidentifier.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean&amp; dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.CompleteAsyncExecuteReader()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalEndExecuteReader(IAsyncResult asyncResult, String endMethod)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.EndExecuteReaderInternal(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.EndExecuteReader(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at Blackbaud.AppFx.Server.AsyncSupport.CancellableSqlCommandHelper.EndExecuteReader(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at Blackbaud.AppFx.Server.DataListLoadProcessor.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Blackbaud.AppFx.Server.DataListLoadProcessor.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at Blackbaud.AppFx.Server.AsyncRequestProcessor`2.EndGetReply(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at Blackbaud.AppFx.Server.AppService.EndDispatchRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)</ExceptionDetails><RootRequestName>DataListLoadRequest</RootRequestName><RequestProcessorName>Blackbaud.AppFx.Server.DataListLoadProcessor</RequestProcessorName></ResponseErrorHeader></soap:Header><soap:Body><soap:Fault><faultcode>soap:Server</faultcode><faultstring>Server was unable to process request. ---&gt; Unable to load data list.  Error converting data type nvarchar to uniqueidentifier. ---&gt; Error converting data type nvarchar to uniqueidentifier.</faultstring><detail /></soap:Fault></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lookup ID is not what's expected by ContextRecordID. Instead you need the constituent's system record ID which is a guid. This value is often given as `QUERYRECID` in the output of constituent query. SQL to get all constituent system record IDs:

```
select distinct [V_QUERY_CONSTITUENT].[ID]
```

What I changed the call to:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(get_list(guid=config.email_list_guid,
                   system_id='c7bb123f-1f9a-49a4-b2fc-456be05bc334'))
```

Note that I changed all instances of `lookup_id` to `system_id`.